# WiFi - OpenNETCF.NET 2.3 - NearbyAccessPoints returns only AP's with low channel numbers

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce, wifi, opennetcf

OS: WinCE 5.0
Hardware: Toradex Colibri (PXA300) with Ambicom USB Dongle (WL250N-USB)
CF 3.5, SDF 2.3

Chris Tacke has showed that connecting an access point is quite easy with the OpenNETCF (see http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/10/28/SDFAndWiFiConnectingToAPs.aspx and http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/08/19/AServiceForScanningAndConnectingToWiFiNetworksFromTheCF.aspx).

That's true and the OpenNETCF functions work well, but the list of nearby AP's doesn't seem complete (m_wzc.NearbyAccessPoints). The AP's with a low channel number (i.e. CH1 or CH2) appear in the array, but the ones with higher channel numbers (i.e. higher than CH7) don't.

In the standard application of WinCE, all AP's are listed (also the AP's with high channel numbers).

When I try to connect with one of the AP's with a low channel number, sometimes an AP with a higher channel number appears in the m_wzc.NearbyAccessPoints list (maybe an AP-connect triggers WZC to complete the list).

Does anyone know why I can't see all AP's? Do I have to consider anything?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: What's the _exact_ version number of the SDF you're using? 2.3.???

Comment: The exact version number of the SDF is 2.3.0.39

Comment: Try with the latest community edition binaries and see if it helps.  Not saying it will, but we've done some work in the networking classes between those versions and those changes might fix what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Chris. With the newest version of the SDF it works fine. Now I see all access points (also them with the high channel numbers).

Comment: Woot! Nice to know we occasionally do things right.

Comment: The links are outdated. Is this what you were talking about: [MSDN: Building a Wi-Fi Discovery Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx)?